# Python, Selenium возможно ли получить новую ссылку от скрипта

Tags: python, selenium

Суть скрипта в том что он запрашивает ссылку, далее переходит по ней, выполняет несколько действий и переходит на новую ссылку. Можно ли сделать так чтобы скрипт отправлял последнюю ссылку пользователю? Я осмотрел документацию selenium`а но ничего не нашёл.

```
import time
import random
import string


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()



driver.get(input("link here"))
driver.implicitly_wait(5)


search_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "SessionForm[firstname]")
search_button = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')



def generate_random_string(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    rand_string = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    search_box.send_keys(rand_string)



generate_random_string(8)


search_button.click()
time.sleep(5)

search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/p')
search_button.click()
time.sleep(5)


search_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'endSessionButton')
search_button.click()
```

Comment: Чтобы в селениуме вывести текущую ссылку попробуйте: `print(driver.url)`

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'url'

Comment: Поменял команду `driver.url ` на `driver.current_url` и всё заработало, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ага, похоже, `url` устарел и убрали его

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения текущей ссылки из [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) используйте свойство [current_url](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_url):

```
...
print(driver.current_url)
```